# After storing the char Y (input from user for looping) in my condition variable, my while loop still not executing?

Tags: c, while-loop, char

I have to make a while loop without update (the ++ or -- process) as below. However, after storing the response from the user (Y) in ans variable, the loop is not executing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    float volt, ohms, power;
    char ans;
    
    printf ("Enter 'Y' to continue : ");
    scanf ("%c", &ans);
    
    while (ans=="Y" || ans=="y");
    { 
        printf ("\nEnter the voltage value (Volt)      : ");
        scanf ("%f", &volt);
        printf ("Enter the resistance value (Ohms)   : ");
        scanf ("%f", &ohms);
    
        power = (volt*volt)/ohms ; 

        printf ("\nVoltage    : %.2f \nResistance : %.2f \nPower      : %.2f", volt, ohms, power);
    
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("\n\nEnter 'Y' to continue : ");
        scanf ("%c", &ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider printing out the character that was read into `ans`? You will also want to check the return value of `scanf`. It must equal `1` which shows it processed one input, your `"%c"`.

Comment: When I run the program, yes it states that the return value is 1. But when I ```printf``` the char of ```ans``` the return value is 89.

Comment: Yes the ASCII value of 'Y" is 89 in decimal. You would want to use the `%c` printf formatter to get it to output as `Y`.

Comment: don't put this semicolon `while (ans=="Y" || ans=="y");` <--- this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just caught it. It is a syntax error. Well, a couple.

You wrote

```
while (ans=="Y" || ans=="y");
```

See the `;` at the end? That means the while loop executes an empty statement instead of the block on the next line.

If you had built this with full warnings on, and a modern compiler you would get a warning about an empty loop.

Also see that you are trying to compare a single character `char ans` against a string literal `"Y"` which is an **array**, not a character. You need to write:

```
while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
```

My GCC version 9.3.0 does this when I use the full warning flags `gcc -W -Wall -pedantic`:

```
c-scanf-test.c: In function ‘main’:
c-scanf-test.c:10:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   10 |   while (ans == "Y" || ans == "y");
      |              ^~
c-scanf-test.c:10:14: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
c-scanf-test.c:10:28: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   10 |   while (ans == "Y" || ans == "y");
      |                            ^~
c-scanf-test.c:10:28: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
c-scanf-test.c:10:3: warning: this ‘while’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   10 |   while (ans == "Y" || ans == "y");
      |   ^~~~~
c-scanf-test.c:11:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘while’
   11 |   {
      |   ^
c-scanf-test.c:8:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    8 |   scanf("%c", &ans);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c-scanf-test.c:13:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   13 |     scanf("%f", &volt);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c-scanf-test.c:15:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   15 |     scanf("%f", &ohms);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c-scanf-test.c:24:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   24 |     scanf("%c", &ans);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can see that you have *many* other errors to fix.